# How do I add radio button and button dropdown together in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, user-experience

Hello Good Developers,

I am trying to put together radio button and button dropdown menu using bootstrap.
just like it is done in bootstrap input-group(Buttons with dropdowns).

The only difference in mine is instead of textbox I want to place a radio button and a Label with it.
Like This
[image: sketch of the view required]

I have tried multiple combinations so far but any solution I am trying isn't being displayed as I want.
Here's what I have done so far

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div style="border: 1px solid;">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                    Default radio
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output is Ugly so far.
[image: Output of Above html]

how can I achieve the output relating to the sketch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that?

If yes, I added `flex-fill` in `input-group-prepend` for `max-width`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend flex-fill">
    <div class="input-group-text form-control">
      <label for="" class="mb-0"><input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">Template 1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the only change i might make is to wrap the check box in the label, but that is my preference so the positioning lines up better  `<label><input type="checkbox">Template 1</label>`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I applied it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have very good [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/). Something like that?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row align-items-center border border-dark">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="Tamplate1" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Tamplate1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```